# Execute NPM module through cordova

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, asynchronous, node-modules

I created an app using cordova and everything is fine, expect I need to use a node module which doesn't have a client-side equivalent because I'm dealing with file write streams etc. I have found Cordova hooks to be my best shot so far, where I create an `app_run` hook to execute a node file that runs a socket server to listen for events  from the client side.

I know, a very longwinded solution, but seems logically correct to me, the issue is that when I do create the server, building the app through Visual Studio 2017, the app launches on my android phone, but VS hangs on the "deploy" stage. I guess that it has to do with the event chain, so I created an asynchronous script like this:

```
(async function () {
    const server = require('http').createServer()
    const io = require('socket.io')(server)

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log('heyo')
        socket.emit('hello world', 'hi')
    })

    server.listen(3000, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log('listening on port 3000')
    })
})();
```

but this doesn't seem to work either, somehow VS hangs on "deploy". If anyone can possibly guide me in the right direction, that would be highly appreciated.

PS: I know the title is off, but every time I use StackOverflow to get help with a particular attempt, I'm told to do it another way, so I'll leave it open.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to use socket.io in your cordova app, there IS a JS client for the web that you need to use and you don't need to use npm for that, just add a link to your client js file in your index file. (should be in a "client" folder when you init socket.io via npm).

```
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 <script>
    const socket = io('http://localhost');
 </script>
```

https://socket.io/docs/client-api/

Comment: I am aware of the socket we client but the package I'm trying to use is a node module which does not have a client package

Comment: Why do you need a package? All you need is socket.io. What is that package??

Comment: Dude, you can't use node packages in cordova! Cordova runs in a webview aka a lesser browser.

Comment: I'm aware, that's why I need to execute a node script that can run in the backend

Comment: Then why do you need socket.io? Just to an Ajax call from your cordova app to your node backend. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.